# Numbers and programming code

Tags: numbering, lyx, sourcecode

This happens when I use programming code and enumeration, how can I add a gap between the numbering and the line numbers of the code. [image]

I'm using this in LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=java,numbers=left,tabsize=2,showstringspaces=false,showspaces=false}
```

Comment: Add an appropriate value for `xleftmargin` in your key-value settings. For example, `xleftmargin=2em`. The default is `0pt`, putting the numbers flush against the left margin (and overlaying with your enumeration).

Comment: I tried `\lstset{language=java,numbers=left,tabsize=2,showstringspaces=false,showspaces=false,xleftmargin=2em}` it moves the numbered bullet as well.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on that, since it seems like you're using LyX, and therefore things may be different (more difficult) compared to regular LaTeX - not all LyX users enjoy using ERTs.

Comment: A not-optimal fix is to change the paragraph setting of the list as well as setting the `xleftmargin`. Right-click the number and choose Paragraph settings, uncheck the "Indent paragraph" box. You won't get the overlap, but the program listing starts below the list number.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Perhaps you can use a combination of your suggestion with the vertical correction suggested in [Vertical alignment of tables when using numbered list in LyX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45575/5764)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides addin `xleftmargin=<size>` to shift the listings over, you also need `resetmargins=true` which resets the indention from list environments like enumerate or itemize.

The frame here is from the `geometry` package to show the alignment with the margins.

[image]

### Code:

Commenting out the `resetmargins=true` below will illustrate the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=java,
    numbers=left,
    tabsize=2,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    xleftmargin=4em,
    resetmargins=true,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{lstlisting}
 public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
     return val;
 }
\end{lstlisting}
%
\item abcd
%
\item
\begin{lstlisting}
 public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
     return val;
 }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```