# Vertical alignment of tables when using numbered list in LyX

Tags: tables, lyx, enumerate

I have a table on my numbered lists but the number is appearing in the middle, I want it to be at the top like normal. This is what it looks like when using tables. (Screenshot below)

I've attached a picture, I want the number 6 to be the top not the middle.

[image]

Comment: The easy way to do this is to use the `[t]` optional argument to `tabular` in LaTeX. There may be an option that can be specified within LyX (can't check now).

Comment: The OP seems to be interested in pure LyX way. He already asked on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=18199) where the option `[t]` has been explained, but he cannot use it.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz The solution is right but need a way to implement this in lyx. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LyX, click inside the table and follow the menu options *Edit* ->*Table* ->*Top*:

[image]

This is equivalent to choosing *Edit* ->*Table Settings...* and then selecting *Top* from the *Vertical alignment*:

[image]

However, this is not the full picture, since your vertical alignment will be slightly off. To correct for this, insert an ERT containing `\tabvcorr` just before the table, and include the following in your preamble (*Document* ->*Settings...* ->*LaTeX Preamble*):

```
\newcommand{\tabvcorr}{\mbox{}\par\nobreak\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}}% Table vertical correction
```

[image]

Now your output should compile to:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment, this can be fixed by giving the optional parameter `[t]` to the `tabular` environment.

For future reference, this parameter can be

- `t` for top justified
- `c` for centered
- `b` for bottom justified

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
                    1 & 2   \\
                    3   & 4
                \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this in lyx?

Comment: @Jeff almost certainly, but I have no idea how to do so. You'll probably get `lyx` directions in another answer